# how to check if the Flow is empty?

Tags: android, kotlin, composable

I am passing data to render the list as a `Flow<>`. If it is empty, instead of the list, I need to display the inscription "No data". How can I set a condition to check if the flow is empty?

```
@Composable
fun HistoryLayout(viewModel: HistoryViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val historyFlow = viewModel.historyStateFlow.collectAsLifecycleState().value
    if (is historyFlow empty???) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                stringResource(R.string.emptylist),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                maxLines = MAX_LINES,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
        }

    } else {
        HistoryTableList(historyFlow = historyFlow)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you might be looking for [onEmpty](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/on-empty.html)

Comment: I considered this option, but I only need one scenario (when flow empty OR not empty). And `onEmpty` executes either 1 (not empty) or all 2 scenarios. Other than that, it doesn't allow composable to be rendered inside `onEmpty{}` function `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Comment: `historyFlow` shouldn't be a flow anymore, it should be just your value, probably a list. You can check if it's empty just like any other list. If I'm not right, please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, i use paging v3 library, so the data comes from the database in the form of a `PagingSource<int, dbEntity>`, from which i can get only `Flow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick helped me solve the problem, however i hope to still find a better solution
From `Flow` i get `LazyPagingItems<...>`, which has `*.itemCount` method.

```
@Composable
fun HistoryLayout(viewModel: HistoryViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val historyFlow = viewModel.historyStateFlow.collectAsLifecycleState().value
    val historyItems: LazyPagingItems<HistoryRecordEntity> = historyFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    if (historyItems.itemCount == 0) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                stringResource(R.string.emptylist),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                maxLines = MAX_LINES,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            )
        }
    } else {
        HistoryTableList()
    }
}
```